# Docker compose with GPU access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

my docker compose file is as follows:

version: "3"

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

I am trying to allow my container to have GPU access. The same thing can happen with docker `run --gpus all` but I want it with docker compose. The yml above produces this error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app.deploy.resources.reservations value Additional properties are not allowed ('devices' was unexpected)
```

I don't understand how can this be a problem since what I used is what the official docs have ([link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/)).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The deploy section is intended for Swarm deployments, and the resources key under deploy is used to configure resource reservations like CPU and memory. For GPU access, you should use a different method.

To enable GPU access in your Docker Compose file, you can use the runtime key under the service, like this:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    runtime: nvidia  # This enables GPU access for the service
```